# Windows Form building failed in second thread

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, .net-4.5, backgroundworker

first of all my issue:

I try to build a winform in a background worker. This Form class only include one webbrowser controll. The form will not build and jump out to main thread. 
Im using c# with .NET 4.5 on Visual Studio 2013 Pro with WinForms

What i do:

Start Background worker

```
    private void bt_dashboard_chat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.bw_webchat.IsBusy)
        {
            this.bw_webchat.RunWorkerAsync(this.auth.getUserName());
        }
    }
```

The worker

```
      {
        String name = e.Argument as String;
        DashBoard.Forms.Chat.DummyChat tmp = new Forms.Chat.DummyChat(name);
        tmp.ShowDialog();
      }
```

Form constructor

```
        InitializeComponent();
        this.wb_twitchchat.Url = new Uri("http://link.tld/" + name + "/chat");
        this.Text = "Chat of " + name;
```

The issue. The thread jumps out at InitializeComponent(); on the line

```
this.wb_twitchchat = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
```

This is the seconde line.

Have somebody any ideas why this happened? Other forms working fine in backgroundworker threads :/

Comment: I means after this line (this.wb_twitchchat = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();) the rest is skipped, nothing happend and im back in the main thread.

Comment: Then it's likely throwing an exception.  Did you check the Output window for an exception, one that isn't breaking execution, perhaps?

Comment: Forgot to check the output :/ Output:"System.Threading.ThreadStateException" in System.Windows.Forms.dll" any ideas? ^^

Comment: i catched the exepction with try catch and i get the following msg: "Das ActiveX-Steuerelement 8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2 kann nicht instanziiert werden, da der aktuelle Thread kein Singlethread-Apartment ist." sorry for the german exception message, dont know how to change it.

Comment: Ok found a solution: The background worker does not support ApartmentState.STA so i neeed to switch to a normal Thread with SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); Now it works fine. The issue was that the Webbrowser control need ApartmentState.STA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception is catch by background worker itself. Use try/catch block around code you are mentioning "The worker".

Catched exception should be something like:
ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

Exception is based on code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += BwOnDoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

    private void BwOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: thx for reply. Yes your right. Finde a solution with Thread's. remove the whole backgroundworker stuff and add a new Thread with SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA). Works fine for now :)